# Unit Test on a c# legacy project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, legacy

I have a problem with unit tests which is as follows:

I'm working on a legacy project where the database has no repository or inherits an interface.

Basically the solution has: a project with models, a project with business rules, database queries and processing for the UI and a project for the UI.

The connection to the database is made by a class specially developed for this and all queries are developed manually and executed by this class.

The classes that have business rules in their vast majority are static with their methods also static and change that would be in the last case (the world ends by example).

I know I need to use MOCK to test the behavior of business rule classes, the problem that I'm kind of lost with.

I would like to know how I could implement unit testing on a product like this without performing a large refactor.

Do the masters have any tips?

Comment: You might want to check out the book Working Effectively With Legacy Code by Michael Feathers https://www.amazon.com/FEATHERS-WORK-EFFECT-Robert-Martin-ebook/dp/B005OYHF0A/ref=mt_kindle?_encoding=UTF8&me=&qid=

Comment: One thing you can do is write very simple thin wrappers and make sure you write them so they are unit testable. Just an idea since we dont know what the code is like.

Comment: The thing about mocks with most frameworks is that they have limitations that will require your legacy code to change - the code has to be designed with testability in mind. For example, my favorite, Moq, can't mock statics, can only mock public virtual methods or interfaces, and has other limitations that require code change in your case.  I do know that there are other frameworks, top of the mind being Typemock Isolator, that do *not* have these limitations. They are powerful (I haven't used them, I imagine that comes at some expense), but also are paid products.

Comment: I'm curious if you read up on TypeMock Isolator whether that solves all (or most?) of the problems you are facing. I've never used it, but have been curious about it for a while.  From TypeMock docs
"It's what a Mocking Framework should be: Powerful. And it's the first of its kind. Which mean you can fake more than just public virtual methods. And you can reach higher test coverage at a fraction of the time. You can fake statics, private, constructors, events, linq, ref args, live, future, static constructors. You name it. " Note: I have nothing to do with that product/company.

Comment: Would using shim be an exit?